# StackExchange ethos; help with caption

Tags: discussion, questions

Many of you may be familiar with the XKCD cartoon [duty calls](https://www.xkcd.com/386/), which portrays a rather dim view of discussions on the Internet:

[image]

One of the things I like about StackExchange, and this community in particular, is that there is often a more positive, helping atmosphere. Accordingly, I modified the cartoon:

[image]

So my question is: what should the rollover/caption say?

Comment: Someone is trying to use a ‘For’ loop to set the elements of a matrix. Maybe I can show them how to use ‘Map’.

Comment: ... but can I really help them translate this pyLab+ routine into Mathematica?

Answer (score 20):

"If I'm the first to post, I'll bet my answer will get at least three up-votes."

Posted at 3:24 AM local time.

Comment: I imagine, the closing quote should be at the end of the post? +1 ofc

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. Nope -- it just states the time I posted the answer and shows how much I'm like the guy in the cartoon.

Answer (score 7):

- "It is certainly a duplicate, the answer is `{##, f[##2]} & @@@ list`, let me just look this up quickly..."